# How to Simulate waterflow sensor network in contiki cooja?

Tags: contiki

Im very new to contiki cooja.Im wanna simulate a waterflow meter in cooja simulator,is it possible ?My aim is to simulate a waterflow meter for tracking water useage.How can i do this in cooja?

Comment: Question lacks demonstration of effort by the OP, needs to include details of what the OP has tried to solve the issue, i.e. own research, google, etc.  Suggest updating the question with more detail as to what you have tried or what research you have carried out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you have to simulate is the device collecting the flow data. It could be a very simple device driver that mocks a flow sensor, by outputting a value that is your flow volume.  Pick this value up from your application and process it accordingly.

For ideas on how to proceed have a look at these device drivers: ["contiki dev"](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/core/dev).

Please, in future try to document the work you did prior to ask a question, as by now it looks like you didn't do any research on this topic.